# How to set condition instead of PropertyName in the SortDescription while sorting a CollectionViewSource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

I want to sort a `CollectionViewSource` but i need to set a condition instead of `PropertyName`.In Fact i want to do the sort below using `CollectionViewSource` in `Xaml`.

```
  Class2Colection.OrderBy(s => s.Id).OrderBy(s =>!s.Id.HasValue));

  <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Class2Colection}">
       <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" Direction="Ascending"/>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="??" Direction="Ascending"/>
       </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: Can you give an example on which condition you want to sort?

Comment: @ Florian Gl:I've already given the example above:`Class2Colection.OrderBy(s => s.Id).OrderBy(s =>!s.Id.HasValue));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply custom sorting logic by implementing your own `IComparer` and setting it to public `CustomSort` property of `ListCollectionView` class. But this is not complete answer to your question and rather a direction where you can move forward.

The simplest way you  can achieve just this

> ```
> Class2Colection.OrderBy(s => s.Id).OrderBy(s =>!s.Id.HasValue));
> ```

in `xaml` is to expose another property in your data class which whould return `!Id.HasValue` and sort by it.

Comment: @AWoodman :Thank you so much.It's not what i'm looking for,but it's works on this case.

Comment: @AWoodman :Sure i will,but now i'm waiting for another solutions.